# Unable to convert xml to object file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb2

my XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<DataSet>
<Data id="asdf">
<DataString>Hello</DataString>
<DataValue>1321512</DataValue>
</Data>
<Data id="hghjg">
<DataString>Hello</DataString>
<DataValue>1321512</DataValue>
</Data>
<Data id="klj">
<DataString>Hello</DataString>
<DataValue>1321512</DataValue>
</Data>
<Data id="hghgjh">
<DataString>Hello</DataString>
<DataValue>1321512</DataValue>
</Data>
</DataSet>
```

My XSD file that is generated using online tool:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="DataSet">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Data" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="DataString"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:int" name="DataValue"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is the Java Code to convert xml to object DataSet:

```
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataSet.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

             dataSet = (DataSet) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\testxml.xml"));

             System.out.println(dataSet);
```

But this response of the code is null for DataSet object.

I don't know where I am going wrong. Plz Help

DataSet file is look like this.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DataSet
{
    private Data[] Data;

    public Data[] getData ()
    {
        return Data;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setData (Data[] Data)
    {
        this.Data = Data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [Data = "+Data+"]";
    }
}
@XmlRootElement
public class Data
{

    private String id;

    private String DataString;

    private String DataValue;

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getDataString ()
    {
        return DataString;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setDataString (String DataString)
    {
        this.DataString = DataString;
    }

    public String getDataValue ()
    {
        return DataValue;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setDataValue (String DataValue)
    {
        this.DataValue = DataValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [id = "+id+", DataString = "+DataString+", DataValue = "+DataValue+"]";
    }
}
```

I have created pojo using online tool.
Plz provide what annotations are needed here
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you post the code of `DataSet` ? Can you test if the `File` you create is valid ?

Comment: public class DataSet
{
    private Data[] Data;

    public Data[] getData ()
    {
        return Data;
    }

    public void setData (Data[] Data)
    {
        this.Data = Data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [Data = "+Data+"]";
    }
}                                                                                                         public class Data
{
    private String id;
    private String DataString;
    private String DataValue;
   // setter and getter with overriding to string method.
  } don't know how to validate many thanks

Comment: Did you create this class by hand ? Or with a tool (like XJC) ? And please edit your original post with the code instead of posting it in a comment (for the sake of readability). :-)

Comment: Do you get any exception? Can you post a stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the `DataSet` and `Data` classes should be annotated:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "DataSet")
public class DataSet {

  @XmlElementRef
  private Data[] Data;

  @XmlTransient
  public Data[] getData() {
    return Data;
  }

  public void setData(Data[] Data) {
    this.Data = Data;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "ClassPojo [Data = " + Data + "]";
  }

}


@XmlRootElement(name = "Data")
public class Data {

  @XmlAttribute
  private String id;
  private String DataString;
  private String DataValue;

  // Standard getters and setters.
  // WARNING: All getters must be annotated with @Transient.

}
```

Here are some rules and explanations:

- `@XmlRootElement` identifies a class as being “bindable” by JAXB. The `name` attribute is optional but, since your XML element names start with an uppercase letter, it must be included, else JAXB will expect `dataSet` and `data` as element names.
- The `DataString`and `DataValue` properties could be annotated with `@XmlElement` but this is not necessary since (1) this is the default behaviour when no annotations are present, and (2) the Java property name and the XML element name match.
- `@XmlAttribute` identifies a property that is represented as an attribute instead of a child element, which is the case of the `id` attribute of `DataSet`. The `name`attribute of this annotation is not necessary since the Java property name and the XML attribute name match.
- JAXB has a weird behaviour: it considers as a property any class attribute and getter without trying to resolve any name-based link between an attribute and its related getter. As a result, with standard getters defined, it will find two `Data` properties, two `id` properties, and so on. Annotating a getter or attribute with `@XmlTransient` disables its treatment as a property, which is what I did to all getters in both `Data` and `DataSet`.
- Finally, since `Data` is annotated as an `@XmlRootElement`, references to it must be annotated with `@XmlElementRef` so that JAXB correctly can correctly establish the link between the property type (in `DataSet`) and the element type (the `Data` class).

------------ UPDATE ------------

Sorry, I went too fast about the `Data` property values... You will need `@XmlElement(name = "DataString")` and `@XmlElement(name = "DataValue")` on the corresponding `Data` attributes. This is, once again, because these property names start with an uppercase letter.

You can check your `Data` property values with the following line (added right after your unmarshalling code above):

```
Arrays.stream(dataSet.getData()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I hope this will be helpful...

Cheers,

Jeff

Comment: Thanks it is working for me in order to get Data object. But Data object values are returning null for all. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [documentation](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_1-A-Survey-Of-JAXB-Annotations.html) for the JAXB annotations. That should give you enough information to determine what annotations you need to add to the `DataSet` class.

According to the documentation, this is all you need:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "DataSet")
public class DataSet {
    public List<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
}

public class Data {
    public String DataString;
    public String DataValue;
}
```

I wish people would take more time to read and understand documentation.

Comment: Plz check my Data file also. I have applied annotation over here.

Comment: And what changed when you did that?

Comment: I have added annotations there. I am able to get the DataSet Object. but still Data array in DataSet is returning null. I am not able to find the solution for this.

Comment: Read the documentation. You should only need `@XmlRootElement`, and the link I provided contains many examples. Do as the examples say.

Comment: I added the one annotation required, following the example at the bottom of the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think Data should not be annotated as `@XmlRootElement` since it is not a root element.

I recommend to generate the JAXB classes using XJC based tooling such as the [Maven JAXB2 Plugin](https://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home).

Comment: I have removed the annotation but it is solving my issue. still data set is null.

Comment: @NamitKhandelwal So what annotation did you replace it with? Did you try to generate the JAXB classes as suggested?

Answer (score 0):

In your case classes should be annotated as follows

```
@XmlRootElement(name="DataSet")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DataSet
{
    @XmlElement
    private Data[] Data;

    public Data[] getData ()
    {
        return Data;
    }

    public void setData (Data[] Data)
    {
        this.Data = Data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [Data = "+Data+"]";
    }
}
```

and Data

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Data
{
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;
    @XmlElement
    private String DataString;
    @XmlElement
    private String DataValue;


    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getDataString ()
    {
        return DataString;
    }


    public void setDataString (String DataString)
    {
        this.DataString = DataString;
    }

    public String getDataValue ()
    {
        return DataValue;
    }


    public void setDataValue (String DataValue)
    {
        this.DataValue = DataValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [id = "+id+", DataString = "+DataString+", DataValue = "+DataValue+"]";
    }
}
```

hope this helps